# should moderators take action based on one meta question with different opinions and not based on clear rules at FAQ?

Tags: discussion, support

I see some moderators take actions like deleting and editing questions that offends asker of question and for reason say things like:

> @Ahmadi : You have been informed multiple times that several users
>   take offense at being called Wahhabi.

is this a fair to a moderator use his power to take such actions that offend users of other sects?

who moderates moderators?

Comment: There was no editing or deleting of questions done. I just deleted 4 comments that were off-topic, non-constructive, and debate-oriented.

Comment: @Ansari I mean delete of word wahhabi. for example in title of question http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2534/what-is-the-justification-of-salafi-schoars-for-destroying-shrine-of-imam-sadiq

Comment: @Ahmadi That title was changed by me, not by any moderators. If you feel it is not appropriate, you are free to roll it back. I am not a moderator. The moderators have a little diamond beside their username.

Comment: @Abdullah yes it was my mistake about mod. but question still remains. specially when change is with no notify. I want to know reason of this action. I consider this not respecting to other sects or even a form of racism because trying to hijack other view by generalizing one name to name of sunni includes not respecting to all other views inside sunni.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, actually part of the reason moderators exist is because there are not hard and fast rules for every possible scenario that might come up. Moderators are exception handlers that deal with cases not otherwise handled by the community using their best judgement.**

Their judgement can be called into question quite easily on meta, at which point it will be come clear whether the community at large thinks their actions are fair.

In the case of extreme issues, there is a team of employees at stack exchange that can be reached via the contact-us link at the bottom of every page. They will be willing to review complaints about moderators and have the authority to deal with them if necessary.

Comment: when I contacted team they simply said our sites are managed by mods and ask in meta.